# Why Does My Put request fail?

Tags: python, http, http-put

Using Python 2.5 and httplib......

I am admittedly a python novice.....but this seems straight forward, why doesn't this work?

```
httpConn = HTTPConnection('127.0.0.1', 44789)
httpConn.request('PUT','/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=', hwSerialNum)
httpResp = httpConn.getresponse()

xmlResp = httpResp.read()

httpConn.close()
```

it returns the following response: `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP 404.......`

Any clues anyone???

Comment: What does your browser say to `http://127.0.0.1:44789/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi` ?

Comment: @eumiro that will use the HTTP GET method, different from the PUT method that he wants to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP 404` means that the resource you requested does not exist. Are you sure that the URL is correct?

Moreover, you put in the body of the request (third parameter of `request()`) a variable that I think is a parameter of the request.

Try the following:

```
httpConn.request('PUT','/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=' + str(hwSerialNum))
```

or maybe (if GET is required instead of PUT):

```
httpConn.request('GET','/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=' + str(hwSerialNum))
```

Comment: I can input this URL into the browser: http://127.0.0.1:44789/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=xxxxxxx and all appears to work okay, meaning i can then query the device and see the attribute has been changed.

Comment: @Kevin if you input it in the browser you use a GET request. Try the second line of code that I posted and see if it works.

Comment: stackoverflow is broken, people can edit their answers after posting to contain other peoples answers and get votes...

Comment: I tried the 'GET' i get no 404 response with that, however, the device attribute does not change either. I tried the GET & PUT with the '+" operand and received and error....i should explain that 'hwSerialNum' is a string. will that be an issue?

Comment: '+' yields: TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: tried this as well: httpConn.request('method','/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=E00K5555"%"' % hwSerialNum), then i tried changing the  % sign prior to hwSerialNum with the '+' as that made sense, but to no avail....still dead in the water.

Comment: that did it....... :) ...... thank you, pretty subtle. curious though, it didn't seem to work on the first pass, didn't give me an error code, but didn't seem to change the device attribute either. so i retried a couple more times, now it seems to work every try......it is a 'GET' as well. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should replace PUT with GET.

You should consider sanitizing the input, trye

```
httpConn.request('GET','/ShazaamMon/setmfgdata.cgi?serial=%s' % (urllib.quote(hwSerialNum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Angelom's answer is concise and correct. For a nice example-filled explanation of using PUT in urllib and urllib2 try http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#data.